# Android AsyncTask don't call onProgressUpdate

Tags: android

I'm try to set progress of ProgressBar from AsyncTask that have to call web services, but the onProgressUpdate is called at end of the function and the ProgressBar don't move.

I'm send the ProgressBar from one Activity and i'm try change progess in doInBackground and this change, but just one time.

```
public class ConectionHttp extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ConectionHttp(ProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        int max = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            int percentageCompleted = i*100/max;
            publishProgress(percentageCompleted);

        }

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        URL url = null;
        String postInformation = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(strings[0]);
            postInformation = strings[1];
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpURLConnection.connect();

            //Información que se envia al servicio web
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            writer.write(postInformation);
            writer.close();

            //Codigo de resultado
            int code = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line = "";
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null){
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return buffer.toString();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Show also how you call your async task.

Comment: `and this change, but just one time.` Yes of course. Your loop is very fast all those calls combine to one. Further in this way at the start of download it does not make sence. Better use it in the while loop.

Comment: Also show your onPostExecute().

Comment: It looks like you are using .get().